# Android: implement ViewPager that only loads new pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I am trying to implement a gallery that always loads a new image, no matter if the user swiped left or right. What I did is to tell my `PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(v,position)` to load image at `mPosition++`, where `mPosition` is initialized to 0. Note that I am not using the suplied `position`.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ImageFactory mImageFactory;
    private int mPosition;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mImageFactory = ImageFactory.instance();
        mPosition = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImageFactory.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((FrameLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);
        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Load Bitmap to ImageView
        mImageFactory.loadImage(imgflag, mPosition++);

        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((FrameLayout) object);

    }

}
```

This however doesn't work, and I'm guessing it's because `ViewPager` caches pages.

So I don't know if I'm right or wrong about my assumption, but I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PagerAdapter has the following method that you can override:

[setPrimaryItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#setPrimaryItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29)
As the documentation states: "Called to inform the adapter of which item is currently considered to be the "primary", that is the one show to the user as the current page."

So that could be used as your hook to update the image. If you need to update pages that are off screen, you will need to keep references around to the views you have instantiated (be careful not to leak Views).

Also, have a look at Jake Wharton RecyclingPagerAdapter. It rocks!

https://github.com/JakeWharton/salvage